# Asp.Net multiple file upload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image-uploading, multi-upload

I've set up an asp.net multiple file upload and it works but not in the way I would expect it to.

On my page I've got 2 image uploaders like so

```
<input type="file" id="gallery" class="multi" accept="jpg" runat="server" />

<input type="file" id="pic1" accept="jpg" runat="server" />
```

My problem is when I upload it uses this code

```
Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
```

To get all the files which were posted but I only want `gallery` images for this specific method.

I have a different method to upload my other image.

I've tried changing it to the following

```
Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files("gallery")
```

But I get an error

> Value of type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.HttpFileCollection'.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's the full piece of code I'm working with

```
Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files("gallery")
For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)
If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/" & i & ".jpg"))
End If
Next i
```

When I use the code from the answer below I get an error saying

> 'Count' is not a member of 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.

**EDIT 2**

This works with uploading all my images

```
Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)
If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/" & i & ".jpg"))
End If
Next i
```

But it uploads every image - I just want it to upload files posted from

`<input type="file" id="gallery" class="multi" accept="jpg" runat="server" />`

and not this one as well

```
<input type="file" id="pic1" accept="jpg" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request.Files("gallery")` is invalid as its a property not a method.

You can get the Posted file from Gallery input by requesting the PostedFile value then save to the file system as you have been doing.

```
Dim hfc As System.Web.HttpPostedFile = gallery.PostedFile
If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
   hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/GalleryImage.jpg"))
End If
```

You can obviously make the file name anything you wish.

Comment: Hi - I'm using this to upload multiple images - I've added an edit showing some extra code i'm using.

Comment: I'm pretty confused by this whole thing at the moment - all I'm trying to achieve is uploading multiple files from a page that has other single file uploads on - it seems so complicated! Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: See my update - It's uploading all images from the page instead of just the ones i'm posting from `gallery` if that makes sense?